# Loop UIScrollView with PageController

Tags: ios, objective-c, loops, uiscrollview, scrollview

I've found a good solution for looping my scrollview, but I'm also using a UIPageControl for showing  what the actual page's number is.

I change the pageControl.currentPage property when the scrollview scrolls, so if you scroll the scrollview more than a half the pageControl shows the new page.
I'd like to keep this feature, but with my actual code the pageNumber is not correct.
I think I should use this: https://github.com/gblancogarcia/GBInfiniteScrollView
But I can't make it work...

Here's my code:

```
-(void)rotateIfNecessary{
    if(scrollView.contentOffset.x == 0) {
        CGPoint newOffset = CGPointMake(scrollView.bounds.size.width+scrollView.contentOffset.x, scrollView.contentOffset.y);
        [scrollView setContentOffset:newOffset];
        [self rotateViewsRight];
    }
    else if(scrollView.contentOffset.x == (scrollView.contentSize.width - scrollView.frame.size.width) ) {
        CGPoint newOffset = CGPointMake(scrollView.contentOffset.x-scrollView.bounds.size.width, scrollView.contentOffset.y);
        [scrollView setContentOffset:newOffset];
        [self rotateViewsLeft];
    }
}

-(void)rotateViewsRight {
    NSMutableArray* controllers = [DashboardFrameUtil getFrameViewControllers];
    DashboardFrameViewController *endView = [controllers lastObject];
    [controllers removeLastObject];
    [controllers insertObject:endView atIndex:0];
    [self resizePages];
}

-(void)rotateViewsLeft {
    NSMutableArray* controllers = [DashboardFrameUtil getFrameViewControllers];
    DashboardFrameViewController *endView = [controllers firstObject];
    [controllers removeObjectAtIndex:0];
    [controllers addObject:endView];
    [self resizePages];
}
```

Then I call `rotateIfNecessary` in my `scrollViewDidEndDecelerating`, everything works fine, but the page calculating.. (when the scrollview resizes itself, it calls the `scrollViewDidScroll` where I calculate the pageNumber:

```
CGFloat pageWidth = scrollView.frame.size.width;
int page = floor((scrollView.contentOffset.x - pageWidth / 2) / pageWidth) + 1;
pageControl.currentPage = page;
```

The pageControl doesn't show the correct page number when the scrollView loops.
Any idea?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's start with:

```
if(scrollView.contentOffset.x == 0) {
        CGPoint newOffset = CGPointMake(scrollView.bounds.size.width+scrollView.contentOffset.x, scrollView.contentOffset.y);
        ...
    }
```

condition is true when scrollView.contentOffset.x == 0, so what for do you add scrollView.contentOffset.x (it's surely = 0) to scrollView.bounds.size.width ?

### UPDATED

*I didn't run code - there can be some mistakes*

If I understand correctly when you, for example, rotate right - last element became first and you want **LAST** page to be showen?

If yes -- the problem with pages is because you change contentOffset all the time and also change 'data source' of scroll view, so there's no correlation between contentOffset and individual DashboardFrameViewController - same DashboardFrameViewController can be at different offsets in different moments of time. So You have to calculate page N according to something else.

For example:

Somewhere in ivar store initial controllers (with initial order):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
        [super viewDidLoad];
        _initialControllers = [[DashboardFrameUtil getFrameViewControllers] copy];
}
```

then you need some method to discover what vc is currently vissible or nearest to center (and store in ivar _currentlyVissibleVC), for example:

```
- (DashboardFrameViewController *)vissibleVC {
     for (DashboardFrameViewController *vc in _initialControllers){
          if (CGRectContainsPoint(vc.frame, CGPointMake(scrollView.contentOffset.x + scrollView.bounds.size.width/2, scrollView.contentOffset)){
               _currentlyVissibleVC = vc;
               return;
          }
     }
}
```

then you can calculate page num:

```
int pageN = [_initialControllers indexOfObject:_currentlyVissibleVC] + 1;
```

Hope helps

Comment: Tha page calculating is not always correct. I have to update the page number in the didEndDecelerating method. But the idea is good, also the + 1 is not needed, because i set the pageController's currentPageNumber and that's an index too (starts at 0).